# Index gets created twice for a certain column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table foo (id, name)
create table bar (id, foo_id, value, ...)
```

We created a foreign key relationship for `foo_id` referencing `foo(id)`, which seems to be creating an index for the same column implicitly. We also have a requirement to create a compound index based on `foo_id, value` in `bar`.

Does it make sense to declare the indexes in the above mentioned fashion or is there a way to optimize index creation in the above case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you use it. The **indexes** are to speedup the queries' executions and **foreign keys** are to make the content of your database consistent.

When it comes to **foreign keys**, here is a part of [Foreign Key constraints documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> **InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys** so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

So everything is ok with the indexes created when the foreign keys are created.

Comment: Yes, but does it make sense to have index on foo_id alone and then another index on foo_id, value

Comment: @priya: Yes, it makes sense, if you perform queries that use such index. That is eg. queries that involve conditions on both columns (`foo_id` and `value`). Because if you have index only on one column, such query will execute slower than when you have two-column index.